# Selenium Browser not visible in hudson

Tags: selenium, ant, hudson

I am running my script through hudson using ant, here script is executing and results are coming , but browser is not displaying while executing scripts
 can u help?

Comment: If using Windows it isn't going to be visible since *usually* the user the build server uses don't have a desktop session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, open services -> hudson -> see which user runs hudson -> login hudson machine using that user and you will see everything